# plasma and infinite acceleration

Tags: simulations, ideal-gas, plasma-physics

I am trying to set up a simulation of particles (they are not any particular kinds of particles, they are just points that repel each other). All the particles repel each other through the inverse square law.

The problem I am having is that the particles keep accelerating away from each other until they "escape" the simulation area.

Thinking about this I realised that if you have any group of particles that repel (like a cloud of electrons) then because they will always feel a force from each other over all distances (albeit with time a small one) then they will accelerate away from each other for ever! 
I guess I could tune the sim so the repelling force isn't so big (which would stave off the problem for a while) but how is it usually handled?

Thanks

Dean

Comment: So are there any attractive forces in the simulation at all?

Comment: No. Its very simple (I'm just getting it started and came up against this problem). Its just 10 particles in a (2d) box that repel each other with force 1/distance.

Comment: Does this box have solid walls?

Comment: yes, and no. There is a switch (is wraparound == true) . If it is then the box is wraparound like a torus (the particles exit right and appear left etc). If wraparound is not true then the particles bounce of the side of the box perfectly eleasticly

Comment: Then there is a bug in the bit of your code that implements that.

Answer (score 0):

I had thought that if you placed two electrons in a vacuum that they would accelerate away from each other without limit. However after speaking to shminux I realised that although they accelerate forever they reach a limiting velocity which depends on their potential energy.

So the particles in my sim will reach a limited v.

Problem was v was too large for my sim to handle.

Hope this helps someone.